# Materialize regex based validation of a series of numbers

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, materialize

[image]

I'm using materialize with a node backend and js front end. I'm trying to submit a form. I have the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">Form Example</span>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" class="validate" pattern="\d{5}" title="Please enter a 5-digit zip code">
              <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="number" id="area" name="area" class="validate" pattern="^(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)$" title="Please enter a valid value (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10)">
              <label for="area">Area (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10)</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" id="submitButton">Submit</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- </div> -->

 <div id="hot-container" class="mt-4">
        <!-- Handsontable grid will be displayed here -->
 </div>
<script>
    // Function to validate the form
    // Function to be called when the button is clicked
    function handleSubmitButtonClick() {
    // Get the values of the input fields
    const zipValue = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    const areaValue = document.getElementById('area').value;

    if (zipValue) {
      
    }

    // Do something with the values, e.g., display them
    alert(`Zip Code: ${zipValue}, Area: ${areaValue}`);
   }

    // Add a click event listener to the button
    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', handleSubmitButtonClick);
</script>
</body>
```

When I enter a non 5 digit number the zip field turns red. The validation is working for this field. However when I enter a number not in the 2-10 range for area there is no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this regex "/^(2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10)$/" once.